# Azure HDInsight Jupyter and pyspark not working

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I created a HDInsight cluster on azure with the following parameters:

```
Spark 2.4 (HDI 4.0)
```

And I try the tutorial of [HDInsights for Apache Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-jupyter-spark-sql-use-portal) with PySpark Jupyter Notebook, and it works just fine.
But ever since I re-run the notebook for the second time or start the new one, and run simple

```py
from pyspark.sql import *
```

or other commands, they all end up with

```py
The code failed because of a fatal error:
    Session 7 did not start up in 180 seconds..

Some things to try:
a) Make sure Spark has enough available resources for Jupyter to create a Spark context. For instructions on how to assign resources see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717038
b) Contact your cluster administrator to make sure the Spark magics library is configured correctly.
```

After this, I also tried pyspark with ssh. When I connected to the cluster through ssh and run

```sh
$ pyspark
```

It shows the following information

```sh
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
```

and stuck right there.

I was wondering If I missed any operation? or it is a bug or something. And How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my observation, you will get this error message when you have issue with “YARN” services example: YARN service is stopped.

**ERROR:** First I had stopped “YARN” services.

[image]

Now I started using Jupyter notebook and when I run the same query, experiencing the same error message as yours.

[image]

**WALKTHROUGH: ERROR MESSAGE**

[image]

**SUCCESS:** All Ambari services are running without any issue.

[image]

To successfully run “Jupyter Notebook” queries, make sure all the services are running without any issue.

[image]

**WALKTHROUGH: SUCCESS MESSAGE**

[image]

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Here are the steps to create a Jupyter notebook and run queries on Azure HDInsight Spark cluster:**

Go to **Azure Portal** => From **Cluster Dashboards** => Select **Jupyter Notebook** => Create **Pyspark** notebook => And execute the queries as shown.

[image]

**You can use interactive Apache for running Pyspark (Python) queries:**

[image]

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-shell

Comment: Thanks for your responds here and msdn. But I find that every time I submit a spark job using yarn and when it finished, this things happens: 1) jupyter not work (with the above connection time limits error); 2) pyspark stuck at the place mentioned above; 3) when submit another job, it stuck at connecting to RM. for really long time. I have tried your ways to go to yarnUI, and also tried with ssh with `yarn application -list` in order to kill the application. But YarnUi cannot connected, and ssh will also stuck at connecting to RM. So is it a common sense?

Comment: @Yuejiang_Li Could you please check out the updated answer. Do let us know if you need any help.

Comment: @Yuejiang_Li If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.